# How did 'litotes' evolve from 'plain, simple'?

Tags: terminology, proto-indo-european, greek

> [litotes (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=litotes&searchmode=none)
>       rhetorical figure in which an affirmative is expressed by the negative of its opposite, from Greek litotes, literally "plainness, simplicity," from ***litos*** "smooth, plain, small, meager,"
>   from PIE root [*(s)lei-](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/indoeurop.html#lei-) "`slimy`, sticky, slippery" (hence "smooth"); see slime (n.).

[Litotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) adds (negative) words and so increases reading time. So how did it evolve from ***litos*** "smooth, plain, small, meager", adjectives all of which contradict the troubles of hypernegation?

I thought about the interpretation of hypernegation as  `slimy`, which would consist with the PIE root. But this guess appears wrong, because PIE is invented and so succeeds Greek.

Comment: Support the creation of a Greek stackexchange (now in the commitment phase) here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101509/greek-language

Answer (score 3):

It's a value judgement, clearly. To be *litos* is to be plain as a positive value judgement; cf. English "plain-spoken". Plainness of speech was extended to avoiding superlatives in speech, as excessively emotive: Ancient Greek culture valued "moderation", which includes understatement. Saying something is "not uncommon" or "not ungraceful" increases processing time, but the praiseworthy plainness from an Ancient Greek perspective is not about processing simplicity (and reading isn't really the point here—these were conventions of oratory). The praiseworthy plainness is about making a show of being reluctant to go overboard in one's positive descriptions.

That's speculation based on what I know of Greek and Ancient Greeks. While https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes reports that  the rhetorical figure is already in place in Homer, LSJ reports that the earliest use of *litotes* to describe it is in late Roman grammarians: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurus_Servius_Honoratus' commentary on Virgil, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aelius_Donatus' commentary on Terence (4th to 5th centuries AD.)